# Filter opto-coupled mains signal for a digital input

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, filter, noise, low-pass

I need to read an input of 220V and convert it in TTL logic 0-5V for my Arduino. If there's a presence of 220V at the input of my circuit, I read 0V in my Arduino, else I read 5V.

In parallel, I have a speed variator for a DC MOTOR 42V/11A with PWM frequency 4Khz.

My problem is, I have noises coming from the motor which cause 0V input in the Arduino without presence of 220V.

Here are the circuits:

[image: Circuit diagrams]

I use a soft Pullup resistor.

There's two part, the first one is without a RC filter so I can clearly see the noises, and the second one with a filter I tried to make, here are the signals I got from each one.

Below the oscilloscope showing the signal with RC filter (2V/DIV 1ms/DIV):

[image: Oscilloscope showing the signal with RC filter]

Below the oscilloscope showing the signal without RC filter (2V/DIV 1ms/DIV):

[image: Oscilloscope showing the signal without RC filter]

So what should I add or change to my circuit to get a smooth 5V?

Comment: Probably a Schmidt trigger.  They use hysteresis to filter noise.  The logic threshold changes based on the current output stage (for example during a high output the logic threshold is '1/3*VCC' and during a low input the logic threshold is '2/3*VCC')

Comment: First and most important. You MUST put a transformer on your AC inputs. Without it, your circuit is a potential death trap. If you do this, you'll find that the noise spikes are probably reduced, but that is just a nice byproduct.

Comment: jbord39- you're right, a trigger is a good idea probably, but i have like 12 AC input like this and and don't have enough spaces to add 12 trigger, so i need to find something with just passif component.

Comment: WhatRoughBeast- u mean i should transform the 220v input to 24V or 12V? i thought about it but same problem, not enough space to put 12 transformer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your advice, i learned a lot .

i found the solution, it was very simple i couldn't believe it when it worked, I just add a 15nF capacitor near the microcontroleur INPUT. So it was the electric wire between the microcontroleur and the output of my circuit that was picking up the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Three things jump out at me.

1) You are clearly seeing magnetic coupling of load current spikes. Your 47 uF cap should be able to filter out "regular" spikes. So connect from the line to your circuit with twisted pair, and keep the circuit as compact as possible. Along this line, you really need to put transformer isolation on your input. Everything up to your opto input is connected to mains, and you clearly do not have much experience dealing with electronics. This is a bad combination, and you may well wind up shocking yourself. And, yes, you say that you don't have room for a transformer. To this I have 2 responses: a) you can get quite small transformers (1" x 1" x 1.5"), and b) the universe doesn't care how restricted your space is - if you touch the wrong point you will get zapped regardless.

2) Your use of soft pullup is a very bad idea. The value of the soft pullup is specified as 20k - 50k, which is so high that it takes very little feedthrough in the optoisolator to produce a detectable pulse. Place a 470 ohm pullup resistor at the input to the uP, connected to the processor supply. Depending on the grade of opto you're using, you may need to decrease your optocoupler input resistor some.

3) In your filter, do not use 1N400X diodes. They are intended as rectifiers, not signal diodes, and are very slow. Instead, use something like the 1N4148.

Finally, if you are desperate, you might try connecting opto pin 2 to pin 4 with a 1 Megohm resistor. This should calm down your input some while limiting leakage currents from the mains.

Comment: WhatRoughBeast- thx for your advice, they are very usefull, but i didn't understand what's the problem with the pullup resistor, can u be more specific please?

Comment: Also, i changed the input resistor of the optocoupler(cny17) to 2.2Kohm to decrease the detectable noises, and then i tried with the Megohm between pin6 to pin4 but it didn't worked, the current was very limited and end up not being enough to turn the transistor ON. another thing, in my country, electronics is not very used so we don't have component as you guys, i couldn't even find a 2*15V transformer or connectors ...

Comment: @lawir - A 50k resistor only requires 100 uA to give 5 volts across it. This means that the opto will require very little input current to produce a pulse. Reducing the pullup to 470 ohms will mean that the opto must drive about 10 mA, and this takes much more input. It also means that you'll need to reduce the input resistor, not increase it.

Answer (score 0):

Your circuits looks very complicate for generating a simple TTL signal. The problem might be the wrong filter design and the pull-up resistor.
Try to make the this resistor smaller, ~4.7kOhm should be a suitable value.

If there are still problems I can suggest you the following circuit. It's very easy and works perfect for me. Also it has a galvanic isolation.

[image: Zero crossing detection]

- **OK1** 4N33
- **D1** 1N4007
- **R1A** 27k (1W)
- **R1B** 27k (1W)
- **R3** 10k

The website is [Zero crossing detection](http://www.hoelscher-hi.de/hendrik/light/dmxdimmer.htm).

Comment: Auoa- which resistor should i make it 4.7K ?? and for your circuit, i can't understand it, it says zero crossing detection, but i can't see the zero detection here, as i see it, it detects the peak of the signal, if the input is above 270V we have a current  of 5mA which should turn the transistor ON, and less then 270V the transistor is OFF. can u explain your cicruit please?

Comment: You should use 4.7k for the _soft pull up resistor_. It should be close to the micro controller. The idea is to make the wire voltage more robust by adding load to it.

Comment: Concerning my circuit: The optocoupler begins conducting far beyond the 5mA (the value you mentioned) at 0.1mA, because there is no heavy load. Thus it generates a low-signal while the input voltage is above 5.4V. So it's no _perfect_, but for most applications useful.